# Delete last record/element from existing XML document using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an XML document of the form:

```
    <RootElement xmlns="http://mynamespace">
      <MyElement>
         <ElementNumber>0</ElementNumber>
         <Data>mydata</Data>
         <MoreData>more my data</MoreData>
      </MyElement>
      <MyElement>
         <ElementNumber>1</ElementNumber>
         <Data>mydata 2</Data>
         <MoreData>more my data 2</MoreData>
      </MyElement>
   </RootElement>
```

I want to remove the LAST `MyElement` record. That is, the one with the `ElementNumber` containing the data of `"1"`. I will ALWAYS need to remove the last `MyElement` record in my XML file, in case that helps.

Comment: Will there always be more than one of these elements?

Comment: If the two elements in your example were reversed, would you still want to remove the one with data "1"?

Comment: Assume there could be just ONE MyElement. That is, a minimum of one MyElement must exist, so account for that. THanks!

Comment: I need to redact that comment. There will ALWAYS be two record/elements of MyElement, at the point of where my code comes into play.

Comment: @alun the "1" is the latest entry added - THAT is the one I want to delete - the LAST one. (long story short - I am adding the last "MyElement" in my own code, however I need a rollback. May sound strange, but I'm wrapping someone elses code, so this is truly the only way)

Comment: @jjack: The point alun is making is, are we removing the one with `ElementNumber` `"1"` because it happens to be the last `MyElement` in the file (which happens to be `"1"` in _this_ case)?  Or are we removing it because we need to remove the last one with `ElementNumber` `"1"`?  Or are we removing it because it is the `MyElement` with the highest `ElementNumber`?  Your explanation is a little confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple:

```
var xmlPath = @"C:\path\to\file.xml";
var doc = XDocument.Load(xmlPath);
XNamespace ns = "http://mynamespace";
var removeMe = doc.Descendants(ns + "MyElement").LastOrDefault();
if (removeMe != null)
    removeMe.Remove();
// uncomment when ready to save
//doc.Save(xmlPath);
```